# symfony does not render CSS

Tags: css, symfony1

I deployed a symfony 1.4 project on a CentOS 6 Server with PHP 5.3.3. I have a problem with CSS.... CSS does not render.
the CSS's are not loaded, the links are correct and also the entries in view.yml

Comment: PLEASE provide more informations, like your view.yml!

Comment: What happens when you request directlyone of the CSS urls in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the css file and it is available and correct when using the view source, the problem is with the html or css coding itself. Symfony doesn't render anything. This would all be executed just like any web server/browser regardless of whether it's a symfony project or not.